# MySQL | Select distincted records

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have that base : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5a24/2 that is a shorthand of WordPress default schema. I have cut out the fields that are not required for that example.

As you can see, in the results I have two times the "Category 1". What I like to do, is to get only the latest instance of the "Category 1".

The correct result for that SQL is the following:

```
POSTID  POSTTITLE   CATEGORYID  CATEGORYNAME    DATE
--------------------------------------------------------------
2   2st Game    2   Category 2  January, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000
3   1st Game    1   Category 1  January, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000
```

I have try the Group By "CategoryID" but while I get only one instance of the Category 1 in the results, I get the older one, not the most early record that belong to "Category 1".

Any idea about that, and how can I fix it ?

Comment: are you sure sql fiddle is processing the query right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.ID AS PostID,
        a.post_title AS PostTitle,
        c.meta_value AS CategoryID,
        d.name AS CategoryName,
        a.post_date AS Date
FROM    wp_posts a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  post_title, MAX(post_date) max_date
            FROM    wp_posts
            GROUP   BY post_title
        ) b ON a.post_title = b.post_title AND
                a.post_date = b.max_date
        INNER JOIN  wp_postmeta c
            ON a.ID = c.post_ID
        INNER JOIN wp_terms d
            ON c.meta_value = d.term_ID
WHERE   c.meta_key = 'matchdayTeamsCategory'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5a24/16)

Comment: That is assuming the post titles are the same. Why not group on post category?

Comment: While in SQL Fiddle is working properly, in my real data that's not correct. In my real data, it return only two records, and it is seem to group my results by PostTitle. I don't realy know what's wrong with it :(. Anyway thanks a lot @JW for your response :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use MIN(Date) with your GROUP BY

Comment: Can you please provide an example ?

Comment: That alone may still produce some weird results, in the `postid`, for example, owing to MySQL's handling of `GROUP BY` and extra columns in `SELECT`

Comment: Correct, the best bet looks like what was posted in the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

use order by date DESC to get "Category 1" latest